# Using ISO 639-2 or ISO 639-3 as authoritative languages list?

Tags: localization

(changed title so as not to confuse future readers)

Is this an authoritative list of languages I can use for my application?

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1 --> http://www.infoterm.info/standardization/iso_639_1_2002.php

> ISO Language Codes
>
> ISO 639-1:2002
>
> Codes for the representation of names
>   of languages -- Part 1: Alpha-2 code
>
> Infoterm has been designated the
>   Registration Authority (ISO 639-1/RA)
>   for the language alpha-2 language code
>   contained in ISO 639-1:2002 "Codes for
>   the representation of names of
>   languages - Part 1: Alpha-2 code /
>   Codes pour la représentation des noms
>   de langue - Partie 1 : Code alpha-2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-1 is old. -3 is newer and more complete.

Comment: Wouldnt http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-2 be sufficient for most web applications?

Comment: If you can tolerate the use of macrolanguages then yes, -2 is acceptable. If you need to choose a specific language then it will be too tolerant.

Comment: hate to bother you - but can you give me an example where you've run into that issue in a practical setting?

Comment: I have not run into it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to be able to localize my Android apps using ISO 639-3. That however the underlying system permit localization in the ISO 639-1 list only. This means that I can't use the built in localisation for minor languages like Yolngu Matha and other Australian languages.

So, it really depends on the underlying system you are developing for, if you can utilize 639-3, 639-3 or not. I have not fund any big support for 639-3, except in linguistics software.