# Get list of all cultures using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a field in my application where the user has to type the culture for the language (Ex. en-US or es-MX). I want to help the user to select the correct format by adding auto completion using the jquery plugin. I need the list of all culture names to accomplish it.

Is there a way to get the list of all culture names using only javascript?

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with jQuery or Javascript

Comment: @Alexander The jquery does his autocomplete it looks like. I don't see jQuery mentioned anywhere else. It's not like he tagged it (unless it has been retagged or removed from the title without me noticing)

Comment: @mattedgod, "... by adding auto completion using the **jquery** plugin..."

Comment: @Alexander I just don't see what is wrong with him explaining how he is implementing auto complete. Most comments here ask posters to be *more* thorough, where is the problem?

Comment: [1] OP doesn't specify whether he has or not a list of "all cultures"  (I suppose he doesn't have a list). [2] OP doesn't show details of the format of the information. [3] There's no explanation of what OP has tried.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867897/using-iso-639-2-or-iso-639-3-as-authoritative-languages-list

Comment: @Alexander All 3 of those are valid points but none have anything to do with your complaint of his mention of jquery

Comment: @mattedgod, you definitely don't get it

Comment: @Alexander Clearly I don't. I actually thought the question made sense, looks like I was the only one

Comment: Yes, my question is if I can do it with JavaScript. I know I can do it in C# or Java, but I wonder if it can be done in javascript and assign the list in a javascript variable without generating json or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the list of culture codes in a flat file somewhere on your server (that way you can use ajax without any XSS concerns). Then load the contents of the file with [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or something similar, parse, and add to the auto-complete plugin.

Here is [a link to a list of codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from a quick google search

Comment: I had thought of this, but I was wondering if JavaScript (or some JS framework) already had this list saved somewhere and I could just access it like in other languages

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. This is one of those lists that's not likely to change very much, most implementations will probably just keep it in a file or a database. Doesn't mean you can't write your own jquery plugin to do it though!

Comment: link is obsilete